# Want to disable wp theme element animation

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to know if there is a code I can add to the style.css that would disable the wp theme animation on the page. Each element either drops in or slides in as one scrolls dn the page.

I bought the wp alchemy theme:  https://demo.mageewp.com/alchem-pro/homepage/  but the theme animation is much slower than the demo so one is past the section before the animation kicks in.

Comment: How's it going @Runner Girl? Were you able to get it going?

Answer (score 0):

So, on a cursory look it does appear than all animation is done via css with no javascript.

All of the styles are in the style sheet animate.css for that theme.

There are several way to accomplish that.

Before doing any of this back up your site and work in a child theme. These resources will explain why you should use a child theme and how to set it up.

I understand it can be daunting, especially when it feels insurmountable. It's not. Take a deep breath and read through the links.

You'll learn how to backup your WP install. Very important! Any number of things could cause damage to your WP install or could cause a loss of the site. If you don't have it backed up you'll have to recreate it all by hand. If you have a backup you could be back up and running in an hour.

Also, you'll learn how to create and use a child theme. That allows you to make changes to your theme without making the changes to the parent theme. If you make changes to your main theme directly and it gets updated you won't be able to update it with the new bug fixes or features without losing all of your changes. I'm sure you see the importance of that.

**STEPS:**

1. Back up your WP install.

   *Without a plugin*

   [Wordpress - Codex: Backing Up Your WordPress Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups#Backing_Up_Your_WordPress_Site)

   [Skillcrush: Backing up Wordpress](http://skillcrush.com/2015/04/23/backing-up-wordpress/)

   *With a plugin*

   [WP Beginner: How to create a complete Wordpress backup for free](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-create-a-complete-wordpress-backup-for-free-with-backwpup/)
2. Use a child them.

   [Wordpress - Codex: Child_Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

   [WP Beginner: How to create a Wordpress child theme video](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/)

   [Smashing Magazine: Create Customize Wordpress Child Theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)

   [Elegant Themes: Wordpress Child Theme Tutorial](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial)

Now the different things to try to accomplish what you are asking. The first is the easiest.

**OPTIONS:**

1. *Copy* **animate.css** to your child theme. Empty the file and save it. Keep in mind you need to recreate the same directory structure that leads to the **animate.css** file. You don't have to copy the other files **animate.css** is the only file you need.

The following are more difficult and require learning some php.

2. Duplicate the file that enqueues and registers the animate.css script to your child theme and remove the enqueue and register calls to animate.css.
3. You could dequeue and deregister the script from Wordpress directly within your functions.php file within your child theme.

Hope this helps,

Tim

Comment: Hi Tim,

I was hoping there was a few lines of code I could add to the bottom of the style.css that would stop the page animation. I don't have the skill to enqueue etc that you mention.

I have no other support and this was my last hope for a solution.

Something like [animate.css="none"|  or [animation="false"] is there such a thing?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Once the css is loaded you're only other option would be to be remove each css attribute for each style. not effective or fast. The first option would be best. I'll give you some resources to help. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thank you for your time and consideration. I'll give it a try.
Best,
Runner Girl

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry I couldn't help more but without the theme in hand there is nowhere for me to go.

Comment: If you are able to get it working please come back and accept the answer. Always happy to answer any questions. If you need more help post a separate question and let me know.